# Storing session landing page in cookie for form parsing (via hidden field)

Tags: javascript, forms, session-cookies

I am looking to pass through the landing page URL of a session as a hidden field in a site's contact form. This is ideal for salespeople so they can see the intent of the user etc.

I have successfully passed through Google Analytics values as hidden fields from the _utmz cookie set by GA.js, but am unable to extract the session langing page.

With this in mind I can see it is necessary to then store the first page of the session into cookie which could then be read and extracted into hidden field on the form.

The logic I am looking to follow would be as follows:

if cookie 'landing_page_url' does NOT exist, set 'landing_page_url' to document.URL
  else do nothing

then on the form pass the stored value for 'landing_page_url' into the hidden field 'landing page'

Would this be possible with javascript, and any ideas about an easy way to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the localStorage: To store your value use `localStorage.setItem (yourVariableName, theValueYouAreStoring);`. To retrieve your value use `var theValueYouAreStoring = localStorage.getItem (yourVariableName)`.

Alternatively,  you can use a cookie. To write one use `document.cookie = 'cookieName=yourValue; expires=Session; path=/';`
To retrieve your cookie use `var cookiePlace = document.cookie.indexOf (cookieName + '=') + cookieName.length + 1;    var yourValue = document.cookie.substring (cookiePlace);`

Comment: Thank for your answer. In your example you are assigning cookieName with 'yourValue'. How would this work if I need to pass through the URL from the DOM, rather than just a  string value? I tihnk that is my main issue.

Comment: To change the url of the page the user is on use 
'window.location = yourRelativeUrl;'
To open a new page with the Url use 
'window.open(yourFullUrl);'